# Elasticsearch - How to delete a list of documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array of _id.

On [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_retrieving_multiple_documents.html) I found out how to retrieve a list of documents from it :

```
GET ads/_mget
{
   "ids": [ "586213440e7d2c7f10fe2574",
            "586213440e7d2c7f10fe2575",
            "586213450e7d2c7f10fe2576",
            "586213450e7d2c7f10fe2577" ]
}
```

This works and returns a list of 4 full documents, as expected.

(sidenote)
I find it weird to have to write "ids" in the query, when it actually acts on the "_id" field.
(end sidenote)

Now I can't figure out how to DELETE these documents from the same _id list.

I tried `DELETE ads/_mget` but I get an error : `No handler found for uri [/ads/_mget] and method [DELETE]`

I tried `_mdelete` instead of `_mget` but it doesn't seem to exist.

I also tried

```
DELETE ads
{
   "ids": [ "586213440e7d2c7f10fe2574",
            "586213440e7d2c7f10fe2575",
            "586213450e7d2c7f10fe2576",
            "586213450e7d2c7f10fe2577" ]
}
```

...but this... just deletes EVERYTHING and I have to reindex the database.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can always use feature of [Delete By Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) and supply payload like:

```
POST ads/_delete_by_query
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "_id" : 
              [ "586213440e7d2c7f10fe2574",
              "586213440e7d2c7f10fe2575",
              "586213450e7d2c7f10fe2576",
              "586213450e7d2c7f10fe2577" ]
        }
    }
}
```

For more infromation about terms query please follow https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: Oh yes that's the one. Thank you!